# What is the fastest way to lookup number in a bucket?

Tags: java, search

Assume there are 5 buckets with each bucket represented by an object, what is the fastest way to look up which bucket a given number belongs to using Java 8 ?

For eg:

```
List <Bucket> listOfBuckets = new ArrayList<>();
```

and each Bucket object has the following properties

```
"Buckets": [{
    "bucketName":"bucket1",
    "lowerBound":0,
    "upperBound":10
}, {
    "bucketName":"bucket2",
    "lowerBound":11,
    "upperBound":20
}, {
    "bucketName":"bucket3",
    "lowerBound":21,
    "upperBound":30
}]
```

for each in {2,15,18,14,22}, find the corresponding bucket.

While one way is to loop through the list for each number, this becomes an overhead if you are checking the bucket for huge list of numbers.

Comment: Lets read a little: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Search_algorithms pick one and go for it!

Comment: Are the buckets sorted?

Comment: The buckets are not sorted.

Comment: I hope you are doing this for educational purposes. Because there is such a thing as a java `HashMap` that does all this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the record, **java offers a wide range of `Map` implementations** (e.g. [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) that use buckets internally. The `HashMap` uses java `hashCode` to arrange them in buckets internally. Alternatively there are other maps with other properties (`LinkedHashMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, ...)

There are even **standard java maps that don't require the exact match of a key**. They implement the [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface. (e.g. a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html))

Alternatively, (e.g. for educational purposes) if you would develop this from scratch, I would use a binary search based algorithm or indexing.

You can apply the ["Bisection method"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or ["Binary search algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). (On the other hand a simple iteration is known as a ["Linear search algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search)). **A binary search will be more efficient than a linear search, especially for large collections.**

A binary search assumes that your elements are nicely ordered. Then you start by trying the center element (`index = length/2`). If your index contains the correct bucket, then you can quit straight away. If not, then take the center of the indexes on the left or right. Repeat until you've found it.

**In code:**

```
if (bucket[index].startId > requiredId) index = index + (length-index)/2;
else if (bucket[index].stopId < requiredId) index = index - (length-index)/2;
else return bucket[index];
```

**Diagram:** The following diagram shows how this algorithm is used to search the number 7 in a list of numbers:

[image: searching steps]

**Alternatively (or additionally), you could add a second (or third) layor of buckets on top of it (like an index).** (That's also [how some database indexes work](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/)). Your structure could look something like this:

```
               bucket[1-70]
               /          \
            bucket[1-25]   bucket[25-70]
           /           \            ...
         bucket[1-15]  bucket[15-25]
          ...              ...
```

**EDIT:**

At the moment your collection is not ordered. If you plan to write your own algorithm, then I would fix that first. You can do this simply by replacing your `ArrayList` by a `TreeSet`. **A `TreeSet` already orders your elements each time you add an element.** However there is a requirement: **your `Bucket` class needs to implement the `Comparable` interface and `equals` method.**

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to use Java 8 *specifically* for this?

```
list.stream()
    .map(n -> listOfBuckets.stream()
                            // Get rid of non-fitting buckets
                           .filter(b -> n >= b.lowerBound && n <= b.upperBound)
                           // Take the first fitting bucket found
                           .findFirst()
                           // No matching bucket? Throws NoSuchElementException 
                           .get()) 
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Note, you have to iterate the list no matter what, so the bucket search will *at least* be bounded by O(n). Because the list of buckets is constant (5), this search is O(5n) which means the execution time grows linearly no matter what.

If you had a variable number of buckets, say m, than a linear search is O(m) and the search would be O(n * m), or O(n<sup>2</sup>), which means the execution time grows parabolically with more and more buckets. At which point, you should consider a cheaper data structure like a tree. That would bring the search time for the right bucket to O(log m), and total search would become O(n log m), or logarithmic growth, which is much better than parabolic growth.

Answer (score 1):

If your buckets are following a pattern as shown in the example above, then you can write a utility method as below :

```
private int getBucketIndex(int number) {
    if(number between 0-10) return 0;
    if(number between 11-20) return 1;
    /*etc*/
}

public Bucket getBucket(int number) {
    return list.get(getBucketIndex(number));
}
```